# Differences between PowerShell ISE and Powershell.exe when using IO.FileSystemWatcher

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following Powershell script running fine in the ISE, but that I mean it runs and waits for files to be created before processing them. The problem is that as soon as I try to run it from the command line it exits at the `$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action` call.

How can I get this to run from the commandline indefinitely e.g. waiting and processing each new file that meets the criteria in the target folder?

I must be missing something, but this is my first attempt at using PowerShell so any advice on how to get this working from the cmd line would be appreciated. If you have any suggestions on improvements I'd love to hear them too.

```
#variables
$folder = 'C:\DE\LIVE'
$filter = 'LOCK.txt'
$data_in = 'C:\DE\LIVE\DATA.txt'
$data_out = 'C:\DE\LIVE\RMIN\data.txt'
$destination = 'C:\DE\LIVE\RMIN\lock.txt'

#setup a file system watcher on the LIVE dir watching the file name and the last write
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "Monitoring: '$folder'"

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    if(Test-Path ($data_in)){
        Write-Host "Processing: DATA.txt"    

        try {
            Get-Content $data_in | Foreach-Object { 
                $output = $output + $_.Trim() + "|"
            }
            $output = $output + "1"
        }
        catch {
            $error[0]
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
            Write-Host "Error ocurred, monitoring stopped"
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------"
        }
        finally {
            Write-Host "Processing: DATA.txt finished"    
        }

        Write-Host "Writing: data.txt to RMIN"

        try{
            $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $data_out
            $stream.WriteLine("ADD DAVE")
            $stream.WriteLine($output)
            $stream.close()     
        }
        catch{
            $error[0]
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
            Write-Host "Error ocurred, monitoring stopped"
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------"
        }
        finally {
            Write-Host "Writing: data.txt to RMIN finished"
        }

        Write-Host "Moving: LOCK.txt file to RMIN"

        try{
            Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
        catch{
            $error[0]
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
            Write-Host "Error ocurred, monitoring stopped"
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------"
        }
        finally{
            Write-Host "Moving: LOCK.txt file to RMIN finished"
        }

        Write-Host "Deleting: DATA.txt"

        try{
            Remove-Item $data_in
        }
        catch{
            $error[0]
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
            Write-Host "Error ocurred, monitoring stopped"
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------"
        }
        finally{
            Write-Host "Deleting: DATA.txt finished"
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------"
            Write-Host "Awaiting Next File..."
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: when you say "running it from the command line" what do you mean? do you copy paste it to the command line?

Comment: I mean running it as a script e.g. `powershell <filepath>.ps1` in a command prompt.

Comment: if you run the following CMD command:
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "&'<filepath>.ps1'"
do you get same results?